# Middle click to open folder in new window

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, mouse

I have selected "single click to open item" in the folder option in Windows 7. Now I want to open the folder in new window when I middle click on any folder. how to achieve this. Suggest any explorer extension or plug-in

Comment: I'm interested in this too, I would like to open folders in new windows with "middle mouse click" (single or double, doesn't matter!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.sourceforge.net/). I've been using it for a year now and it's lightweight, configurable and easy to use. An alternative is [Clover](http://ejie.me/) which adds Chrome style tabs to Explorer, however, on Windows 8, the contextual ribbon tabs somewhat are hidden.
Hope this helps :).